# Getting the image size using the new Image() returns 0's

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load a image from the input text path and set its size for previewing.

So I have this object to process the settings:

```
var Settings = {
    // some other variables
    settLogoLeftVisibility: "true",
    settLogoLeftPath: "OS_logo.jpg",
    settLogoRightVisibility: "true",
    settLogoRightPath: "OS_logo.jpg",
    // some more variables
    load: function() {
        // load the settings from localStorage, or load the defaults
        // set the image path and resize it
        var tempLogoLeftWidth;
        var tempLogoLeftHeight;

        function tempLogoGetWH() {
            tempLogoLeftWidth = this.width;
            tempLogoLeftHeight = this.height;
            return true;
        }
        tempLogoLeft = new Image();
        tempLogoLeft.onload = tempLogoGetWH;

        if (localStorage.settLogoLeftPath) {
            tempLogoLeft.src = "../logos/" + localStorage.settLogoLeftPath; 
        }
        else {
            tempLogoLeft.src = "../logos/" + this.settLogoLeftPath;
        } 
        alert(tempLogoLeft.src);
        alert(tempLogoLeftWidth);
        alert(tempLogoLeftHeight);
    }
}
```

Thing is, it alerts the correct path, but both tempLogoLeftWidth and tempLogoLeftHeight are alerted as undefined, so I cant process them further and set the sizes I need.

Edit: I call the Settings.load(); at the very end of my settings.html page, like this:

```
// some tables, inputs and buttons
<td>Left logo preview<br>
<img class="settingsLogo" id="settingsLogoLeft"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="settLogoLeftVisibility" value="true" onChange="Settings.preview();"> Enable left logo<br>
<input type="text" id="settLogoLeftPath" size="20" onChange="Settings.preview();"> File name (logos/x.yyy)<br>
<script>
Settings.load();
Settings.preview();
</script>
</body>
```

There are no errors in the Chrome JS Console.

Any ideas?
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: These three `alert`s will be executed **before** your `tempLogoGetWH` callback function, therefore valules of width and height will be undefined. Move them at the very bottom of `tempLogoGetWH` and everything will be fine.

Comment: This is happening because your image load `tempLogoGetWH`  is **not**  executed and you are trying to alert `height, width` **before** it executes.

Comment: That explains a lot, works now! Thank you, guys! OT: How do I set this as "asnwered" now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works ok

```js
var Settings = {
    // some other variables
    settLogoLeftVisibility: "true",
    settLogoLeftPath: "OS_logo.jpg",
    settLogoRightVisibility: "true",
    settLogoRightPath: "OS_logo.jpg",
    // some more variables
    load: function() {
        // load the settings from localStorage, or load the defaults
        // set the image path and resize it
        var tempLogoLeftWidth;
        var tempLogoLeftHeight;

        function tempLogoGetWH() {
            tempLogoLeftWidth = this.width;
            tempLogoLeftHeight = this.height;
            alert(tempLogoLeft.src);
            alert(tempLogoLeftWidth);
            alert(tempLogoLeftHeight);
            return true;
        }
        tempLogoLeft = new Image();
        tempLogoLeft.onload = tempLogoGetWH;
//this is not important I just put anything to make it work the key is where alerts are
        if (localStorage.settLogoLeftPath) {
            tempLogoLeft.src = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=b8d3dc7bcd05e3ba58eb1089d4838b9c'; 
        }
        else {
            tempLogoLeft.src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=b8d3dc7bcd05e3ba58eb1089d4838b9c";
        } 
        
    }
}
```